# Convert Array to List of Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, css-selectors

need a help with converting array, for example "01b,02b,03c" to a list of selectors "#01b,#02b,#03c which I can use as list of selectors in the jQuery

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="01b"/>
<input type="radio" id="02b"/>
<input type="radio" id="03c"/>
```

JavaScript

```
var arr = ['01b','02b','03c'];
// var newArr = would be a list of selectors, like ['#01b','#02b','#03c'];

// then I would use it in the JavaScript to pre-check radio buttons
$(newArr).prop('checked', true);
```

So output would be like

```
<input type="radio" id="01b" checked="checked"/>
<input type="radio" id="02b" checked="checked"/>
<input type="radio" id="03c" checked="checked"/>
```

I have tried to use something like

```
var newArr = arr.each(function() {
 return '#'+ $(this);
});
```

But it seems to be far from valid;

Comment: why not simply do `$(arr).each(function(i) { $("input[id=" + arr[i] + "]").prop("checked", true)})` ?

Comment: Hi, thank you, it should be enough, thank you :) I will need to fix another problem on my side first. And then I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

arr.each don't return the result back. So, the newArr in you're example is undefined.

You can use arr.map, which creates the new array of mapped elemenents and returns it back.

```
const newArr = arr.map(function(el) {
    return '#' + el
})
```

Comment: Hi, I need some time to process it. It looks like there is another issue on my side, so I need to fix it first to test your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` to convert the array of strings from one format to another. Also note that you will need to call `join()` to serialise the array back to a string with comma separators for it to be recognised in the jQuery object:

```js
var arr = ['01b', '02b', '03c'];
let selector = arr.map(s => `#${s}`).join(',');
$(selector).prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="01b" />
<input type="radio" id="02b" />
<input type="radio" id="03c" />
```

Alternatively, you can simply use a class.

Comment: Hi, I need some time to check it out. It looks like there is another problem on my side, so I need to fix it first to test your solution.